# Premature end of line Weka error

Tags: csv, weka, data-mining, arff

I'm new to Weka and I have to use it for a University project. So, I created a .csv file and when I try to upload it to Weka, it says: "not recognised as a CSV data file. Reason: 1 problem encountered on line 2". 
Then, if I open the .csv file with Notepad and then save as .arff file, when I try to open it again with Weka, in this case I get another error message: "not recognised as an arff data file. Reason: premature end of line, read Token[EOL], line 8". 
Please help, I don't know much about working with Weka and really don't know what could be the problem, even though I did a lot of research about this problem.

This is the file: https://app.box.com/s/adfpf1zatgpl5mo20u5hdd1gnqihnq40

```
@Relation "PIB_Rata inflatiei" 

@Attribute "PIB"    NUMERIC 
@Attribute "Rata_inflatiei" NUMERIC 

@Data 
30624.3,20780.9,27980.4,31920.3,37657.0,37168.3,35838.9,41978.0,36183.4,37439.0,40717.1,46174.0,59867.6,76217.6,99699.2,123533.7,171540.2,208185.1,167421.6,167998.1,185362.3,171664.6,191548.1,199325.9,177956.0
128.0,211.2,255.2,136.8,32.2,38.8,154.8,59.1,45.8,45.7,34.5,22.5,15.3,11.3,9.0,6.6,4.8,7.8,5.6,6.1,5.8,3.3,4.0,1.1,-0.6
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ARFF format (as well as CSV) instances are rows, and attributes are *columns*.

Your file thus has too many columns, ever row must have exactly.two values.